# Change location of swagger JSON using Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to configure Swashbuckle so the generated JSON file can be accessed using the URL {root}/swagger.json.

I've manipulated a number of settings but have been unable to get it to work.  Here are some examples:

```
// This works!  JSON file is located at http://{root}/swagger/docs/v1
this.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RootUrl(x => baseUrl);
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", title);
}).EnableSwaggerUi();

This works!  JSON file is located at http://{root}/swagger/docs/swagger
this.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RootUrl(x => baseUrl);
    c.SingleApiVersion("swagger", title);
}).EnableSwaggerUi();

// This does not work.  JSON file is located at http://{root}/swagger
this.EnableSwagger("{apiVersion}", c =>
{
    c.RootUrl(x => baseUrl);
    c.SingleApiVersion("swagger", title);
}).EnableSwaggerUi();

// This does not work.  JSON file is located at http://{root}/foo/swagger
this.EnableSwagger("foo/{apiVersion}", c =>
{
    c.RootUrl(x => baseUrl);
    c.SingleApiVersion("swagger", title);
}).EnableSwaggerUi();
```

How can we configure Swashbuckle so the file is named "swagger.json" and it is accessed from a different path from "/swagger/docs" - preferably the root of the application?

Comment: Did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 16):

In case anyone is still looking:

[this approach](http://eatcodelive.com/2017/05/19/change-default-swagger-route-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api/) worked for me:

> app.UseSwagger() changes:
>
> ```
>  app.UseSwagger(c =>
>  {
>       c.RouteTemplate = "SampleApi/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
>  });
> ```
>
> app.UseSwaggerUI() changes:
>
> ```
>  app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
>  {
>       c.SwaggerEndpoint("/SampleApi/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sample API");
>       c.RoutePrefix = "SampleApi/swagger";
>  });
> ```